# Ошибка при отключении хоста в Netcode for Gameobjects в Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d

Делаю сетевую игру используя Netcode for Gameobjects в Unity. Есть основной сетевой менеджер, наследуемый от NetworkBehaviour и в нем мы подписываемся на события подключения и отключения клиентов от созданного нами хоста:

```
NetworkManager.Singleton.OnClientConnectedCallback += NetworkManager_Server_OnClientConnectedCallback;
NetworkManager.Singleton.OnClientDisconnectCallback += NetworkManager_Server_OnClientDisconnectCallback;
```

При подключении клиента мы заносим его данные в сетевую переменную (список):

```
    private NetworkList<PlayerData> playerDataNetworkList; 
    playerDataNetworkList = new();

private void NetworkManager_Server_OnClientConnectedCallback(ulong clientId)
{
    playerDataNetworkList.Add(new PlayerData{
    clientId = clientId
    });
}
```

А когда клиент отключается мы удаляем его из этого списка:

```
private void NetworkManager_Server_OnClientDisconnectCallback(ulong clientId)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < playerDataNetworkList.Count; i++){
        PlayerData playerData = playerDataNetworkList[i];
        if(playerData.clientId == clientId){
            //Disconnected
            playerDataNetworkList.RemoveAt(i);
        }
    }
}
```

Так вот, если мы создаем сетевую игру как хост и отключаемся - то никаких ошибок не возникает, так же не возникает ошибок, если подключаются или отключаются клиенты.. ОДНАКО - если кроме нас к нашей игре присоединился хотя бы один игрок и мы после этого отключаемся, выскакивает все время ошибка:

```
NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
Unity.Netcode.NetworkList`1[T].MarkNetworkObjectDirty () (at Library/PackageCache/com.unity.netcode.gameobjects@1.6.0/Runtime/NetworkVariable/Collections/NetworkList.cs:78)
Unity.Netcode.NetworkList`1[T].HandleAddListEvent (Unity.Netcode.NetworkListEvent`1[T] listEvent) (at Library/PackageCache/com.unity.netcode.gameobjects@1.6.0/Runtime/NetworkVariable/Collections/NetworkList.cs:536)
Unity.Netcode.NetworkList`1[T].RemoveAt (System.Int32 index) (at Library/PackageCache/com.unity.netcode.gameobjects@1.6.0/Runtime/NetworkVariable/Collections/NetworkList.cs:503)
NetworkGameManager.NetworkManager_Server_OnClientDisconnectCallback (System.UInt64 clientId) (at Assets/Scripts/Multiplayer/NetworkGameManager.cs:186)
Unity.Netcode.NetworkConnectionManager.OnClientDisconnectFromServer (System.UInt64 clientId) (at Library/PackageCache/com.unity.netcode.gameobjects@1.6.0/Runtime/Connection/NetworkConnectionManager.cs:850)
UnityEngine.Debug:LogException(Exception)
Unity.Netcode.NetworkConnectionManager:OnClientDisconnectFromServer(UInt64) (at Library/PackageCache/com.unity.netcode.gameobjects@1.6.0/Runtime/Connection/NetworkConnectionManager.cs:854)
Unity.Netcode.NetworkConnectionManager:DisconnectRemoteClient(UInt64) (at Library/PackageCache/com.unity.netcode.gameobjects@1.6.0/Runtime/Connection/NetworkConnectionManager.cs:877)
Unity.Netcode.NetworkConnectionManager:Shutdown() (at Library/PackageCache/com.unity.netcode.gameobjects@1.6.0/Runtime/Connection/NetworkConnectionManager.cs:976)
Unity.Netcode.NetworkManager:ShutdownInternal() (at Library/PackageCache/com.unity.netcode.gameobjects@1.6.0/Runtime/Core/NetworkManager.cs:980)
Unity.Netcode.NetworkManager:OnDestroy() (at Library/PackageCache/com.unity.netcode.gameobjects@1.6.0/Runtime/Core/NetworkManager.cs:1046)
Unity.Netcode.NetworkManager:OnApplicationQuit() (at Library/PackageCache/com.unity.netcode.gameobjects@1.6.0/Runtime/Core/NetworkManager.cs:1040)
```

Вылетает она именно при попытке удалить игрока из списка при отключении:

```
playerDataNetworkList.RemoveAt(i);
```

Однако, как избавится от нее - я так и не нашел решения. Пробовал проверять на наличие .NetworkManager.Singleton что он не равен null, либо же что сам список не равен null перед удалением - но через дебаг показывает, что все есть.. Но ошибка при этом тоже. Что делать? Подскажите, кто сталкивался с подобным?

Была идея, что надо отписываться от **NetworkManager.Singleton.OnClientDisconnectCallback -= NetworkManager_Server_OnClientDisconnectCallback;** при отключении, но как это сделать, если стандартный OnDestroy() у сетевых объектов не работает как обычно? Да и нужно ли это вообще? Уже всю голову сломал (((